# New accounts being created for just a question.?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

I have recently encountered a lot of questions by new users that create an account only for that particular question of theirs.

What is annoying is the fact that these users leave the question without marking an answer or even checking the given answers.

There must be a way to keep a check on such posts. Most of the answers to such questions are either already posted or easily available through a little bit of googling.

We could employ a way such as XDA assist for keeping the site clean and solutions easily accessible.

Is there any other way of keeping a check on such posts?

Comment: What are you actually suggesting we look for? What is the exact criteria for the sort of post you're talking about? And once you have this list, what would you do with them?

Comment: don't worry about it, if it reaches certain criteria it is auto deleted. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/185528

Comment: @Oli I expect a way similar to what XDA adopted to deal with such users.

Comment: @adeen-s What is XDA? How do they deal with this? I have no frame of reference.

Comment: @Mateo that's insightful but it still cannot help those new users.

Comment: @Oli XDA is a community for developers. Recently many people started joining it for help with their devices. What they did is to create a new place called XDA Assist where people don't have to make an account. Just ask their question and they are directed to the relevant forum by the moderators.

Comment: You're posting a feature-request without specifying exactly what your feature-request is about. Can you explain that XDA thing in details in the question? Maybe it's interesting, but as of now your question is just a vague statement about part of the system being broken on which people can't really vote, since they are not really entitled to know what XDA's stuff is about. Personally, I have no idea about what XDA Assist is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid the question was discussed already in many ways. Many solutions were proposed and many were shot down for good reasons. The conclusions were always simple:

- No one else but OP can decide if a solution is valid *for* OP.
- Since OP is not the only one to vote on an answer, the problem is relatively small. Sooner or later, a good answer will find its "voters".
- As soon as at least one of the answers has at least one upvote, the question is considered to be answered.

Furthermore, I am having difficulties with the thought that every minor problem would the result of some kind of a "bad intention". Remember the rules here are a bit different from what most people are used to, and we all started with creating an account for a single question or answer.

The fact that some users do not vote on- or mark their question is probably in most cases the result of not being familiar with how things work here. Also in most cases, a friendly reminder, or just inquiring if (one of) the answer(s) *did* work is enough to "bring OP to live". If not, It might be annoying to you, but objectively, it means nothing.

Comment: That clears up the doubts in my mind. Thanks.